# Use of the word "over"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I find the use of *over* a bit confusing at times in sentence like:

- *the shop is over the street*: does it mean on the street or on the other side of, across, the street, or both?
- *walk over the street*: walk on the street or across, to the other side, of the street?
- Come over to me, he said: does it imply you have to cross a place to reach him?

Comment: @Josh - What is so interesting about the _napping_ vs _taking a nap_ ngram? And, perhaps more importantly, what does that have to do with this question? P.S. You might find [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+was+napping%2CI+was+taking+a+nap&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) interesting, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When used in respect of spatial relationships, the core sense of ***over*** is *above* (vertical displacement). But it also has strong associations with *beyond* (horizontal displacement) and *across* (calling attention to the intervening space or pathway which must be *crossed/traversed* to get from *here* to *over there*).

Looking at OP's specific examples, if you say a building is *over the road/street* that will almost always mean *on the other side* (i.e. - *opposite* the side the speaker is on, or the "current" side being spoken of). If the concept of *crossing* the street isn't relevant, the speaker would use [***up*** or ***down***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/399/), not ***over***.

Idiomatically, you wouldn't normally ***walk*** over the street (you either *cross it*, or *walk along* it).

But *"Come over here"* doesn't necessarily imply anything more than *crossing the intervening space*. You can just as naturally call this out to someone on the same side of the road, bridge, or other barrier as yourself. The actual distance doesn't need to be far either - you could reasonably say *"Sit over here"* to someone who's already very close to the seat you're inviting them to take.

---

TL;DR: Whilst ***over*** *can* have connotations of being *above* something, or crossing a "barrier", it can also be used in contexts where the only thing being traversed is a (literal or figurative) *distance*. The usage [*"dates back **over** centuries"*.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20hope%20it%20be%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22dates%20back%20over%20centuries%22&tbm=bks)