# Is there any difference in meaning between "Come down to see us" and "Come to see us"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference in meaning when people say *Come **down** to see us* instead of *Come to see us*.

Does it still suggest any trace of meaning against *Come to see us* where this particle is not used?

Are there any register change, for instance, or any other shades of meaning?

I have a non-native speaker's feeling that it adds politness and a tiny bit more formal than *come to see us*.

Added later: [walking up/down the street is slightly different matter: I think up and down is a case of idiomatization expressing the meaning of one pacing the street going first in one direction, then back.

In my question I deal with particle/no-particle case trying to understand if a particle of its own brings in a meaning as opposed to zero partile. Clearly, one should beleive that a change in the word alters the meaning or should be motivated somehow by a context.]

((Sorry for stirring such an exchange of opinions about one innocent word. It is something that is like a blind spot for me: how can you use or not use something so noticeably visible without a feeling that there is a message behind.))

Comment: come down means the person inviting you lives north of you.  Compare: come up and see us (you live to the south of the speaker) Also: come out and see us [in the countryside, leave the city]. This is not related to formality or politeness.

Comment: Or *Come **up** to see us* or *Come **out** to see us* or *Come **in** to see us*, etc. It would rarely iff ever make any difference whether you included any one of several prepositions in such contexts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Walking up/down a level road/street](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/399/walking-up-down-a-level-road-street)

Comment: English isn't that precise. You can go ***up*** or ***down*** to see someone without knowing or caring if they live north or south of you, OR at a higher / lower altitude. Same as walking up / down the road. But note that there IS a difference if you walk across the road, whereas it doesn't necessarily imply anything different if you're invited to come across and see someone (nobody necessarily knows or cares what exactly you might "cross" to get to the other place).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  **I disagree completely with you**. If I ask a Canadian friend to visit and I live near Boston, (which in fact I do) I might very well say "come down". But only because the Canadian friend lives to my north. Conversely, I might say: come up and visit you, to them.  Of course, I might also just say: Come and visit me. And if a friend invites me to western Massachusetts, I might well say: come out and visit you. **This is not exactly the same as walk up/down a road**.

Comment: @Lambie: You're just looking for a point you can take issue with. I live south of London, and I certainly wouldn't be likely to say I'm going down to Scotland to visit a friend. But obviously people say "We're going **down / up** the pub* without taking any notice of relative elevation and/or north/south orientation. You shouldn't be telling learners that they *must* be "accurate" with such prepositions, when  the natives don't take much notice.

Comment: ...also, Brits in particular often talk about *going **up / down** town* completely interchangeably. Most of us don't use / recognise the specifically AmE form ***downtown** [CityName]* for "city centre" (or "the old part of town").

Comment: When I was a kid my father was fond, on a Sunday, of listening to a BBC radio programme called 'Down Your Way'. Each week it visited towns and villages around the United Kingdom, spoke to residents and played their choice of music. It ran from 1946 to 1992. I found it entertaining to hear people with regional accents trying to 'talk proper' for the BBC.

Comment: My friend from Cardiff (Wales) talks about 'going down the town' when she means 'going to the central part' of whichever town she is in.

Comment: I don't care at all about England/Scotland and Wales in this instance. The US and Canada are HUGE which is why people do say down, up and out to. And it **does have meaning on this side of the pond** and it isn't like down the pub etc. or street. I am not looking for a point I can take issue with. My point has validity and  your blithe assertion re the meaninglessness of up/down the pub or street is NOT the point in NA.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I do think that Lambie has a point: "down" is significantly more likely to be used when the direction of travel is roughly to the south. However, the relevant usage, I believe, in practice varies regionally and cannot be relied on to indicate an actual direction.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Up is just like down. People in NYC often go north from there for weekends. As well, as **out to Long Island**. So a person on the telephone north of NYC with a person in NYC might very well say: Are you coming up for the weekend? If you live in Devon, I can well imagine a person saying: He was down for the weekend. [i.e. from London]. Like I said, this is about long distances, ones one travels by car, bus or train. Not neighborly jaunts to a local establishment. [The downtown/city centre thing here is completely irrelevant.]

Comment: @Lambie While I think you have a point, the usage of "go down" to mean "travel roughly to the south" is I think a bit beside the concern of the question as I read it, which seems to me to be more about whether adding "down" (or "up") significantly changes the meaning od lewvel of formality of the statement.  Also, my experience "down" can be used to mean "towards a population center.  People in New Jersey often speak of "going down to the city" although New York city lies to the North-east. Overall I don't think the implications of "down" or "up" are consistent enough to rely on.

Comment: All these comments are perhaps diagnostic of an 'opinion based' question.

Comment: @ 
Michael Harvey
 I don't think the **question** is opinion-based at all, or no more than any usage issue. I think the **side-issue** of the meaning of "down" or "up" in such a statement is somewhat .opinion-based, although sources could probably be cited. I would oppose closing the question as opnion-based

Comment: Think about this: Why would I or any reasonable English speaker add up or down or out to the verb come if the person I was addressing was not directionally north, south or east/west of me? I add: huh? Really. This would imply we just say "whatever" and I do not believe this is so. Think of the British saying: come out to India or Kenya, etc. A bit dated but still. And interestingly there, out would mean "out of England or the UK" and NOT south or north. I also do not think this is opinion based **at all**. However, it is listening based....

Comment: @Lambie - British people still say 'out there' about places like 'Saudi', Australia, etc.

Comment: @David Siegel: I never suggested that there's ***no*** connection between *going up/down [to some place]* and the possibility of that place being at a higher altitude or more northerly than the potential traveller's *current* location. All I did was point out that we ***can and do*** (sometimes, often; who cares?) use those prepositions without regard to the actual physical topology. Learners shouldn't assume it's some kind of syntax error if a person living in St Albans talks about going up to London. Like I said, English simply isn't that precise and/or "fixed".

Comment: @FumbleFingers But often it is due to the topology. Even for a road, depending on how the speaker views it.  Ergo, there is a difference between come down and come. Without an explanation, a learner can go very wrong.

Comment: I don't think the OP here actually *needed* to be told that ***up / down*** after verbs like ***come, go,...*** often reflects relative height or latitude between source and destination. He's aware that we ***do*** sometimes include such prepositions, and he's simply asking whether, say, *Come **up** and see me* necessarily carries a different meaning to the same without the optional preposition. To which the answer is ***No**!* It's a bit irrelevant that someone living in a basement south of the invitee would probably use ***down*** rather than ***up*** in such contexts.

Answer (score 2):

> (1) Come down to see us.

May suggest that the travel would be to a place to the south of, or lower in elevation than, the starting point, as the comments by user Lambie suggest. But I would say that usage on that point varies a good deal.

In any case, aside from a possible difference in direction of travel, such forms as:

> - (2) Come over to see us.
> - (3) Come to see us.

have no difference in meaning or register, and all three may be used totally interchangeably if "down" is not ruled out by direction.

Comment: I don't think one can say that usage varies. I'd say a particular speaker might say it or not (not use the down). It is all situational. And for me, it is different than down/up the street/road and even down/up the pub, which, by the way, can be very logical from a speaker's point of view and have meaning. come down and see us or come up and see up or come out and see us implies a long distance. A place you have to travel to by car, bus or train.

Comment: @Lambie did you consider my example of people in central or western NJ (say around Princeton, where I used to live) commonly saying "down to NY" for travel of 1-2 hours by car or train to the North-east. This was very common usage in that area. In East Lansing when I was in college one often spoke of going "down to Lansing" but the travel was largely to the west, and a bit north. say 30-45 minutes by bus, which was the common method of travel for those I was talking with. Lansing is the state capital and a much larger city.

Comment: David, I lived in NYC a long time. I believe you when you say it but I must say I find it very weird just like a lot of other stuff in Jersey. People in NY said: I'm going down to the Jersey shore this weekend. And that's south. So, maybe usage does vary...a bit.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, People in Jersey said "down the shore" also, which was usually WSW or just SW.  as for weird local usages, how about "Port of Authority" for the 40th street bus terminal? I think you are expecting more logic in usage where historical accident has a significant effect.

Comment: I never heard Port of Authority, and I lived very close to the bus station on 44th and 9th. It's just: The Port Authority [of New York and New Jersey].

Comment: In BE, I agree with David Siegel, but with the use more aligned to a southerly direction (rather than altitude): People in Scotland would go down to London, and people on the South Coast would go up to London.

Comment: @Greybeard Tht was more Lambie's position  than mine, although I agree that it is often said that way.

Comment: @Greybeard Perhaps you might inform your fellow countryman of that.

Comment: @Lambie: Can't you just drop it? We don't think *exactly* the same on this point, but I don't need you or anyone else to keep telling me how I "should" speak, by your logic!

Comment: @FumbleFingers And I don't need anyone saying that up/down/out/over have no meaning in English at all with verbs like come/go etc. They very often do have meaning.

Comment: There are dozens of written instances of [***up** to London from Oxford*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22up+to+london+from+oxford%22) in Google Books. But there are also dozens of instances of [***down** to London from Oxford*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22down+to+london+from+oxford%22) The fact that Oxford is hundreds of feet higher ***and*** several miles north of London clearly isn't a "decisive" factor in choice of preposition.