can anyone explain about what "up" means in these sentences?
Please don't mind the excerpts being too long.

“Poor lame Jennie sat at her window, looking out upon the dismal,
narrow street, with a look of pain and weariness on her face.“Oh,
dear,”she said with a sigh,“what a long day this is going to be,”and
she looked wishfully up the street.”

and one from Harry Potter.

“He kept looking left and right up the street, still hoping to see the
person who had made the cracking noise. ”

Can I change look up the street to look at the street? what is the difference?
Here is another one from Harry Potter.

“Scowling, Harry readjusted Dudley on his shoulder and made his slow, painful way up number four’s garden path.
”

Also, can I change make his way up the path to make his way along the path, and is there a difference?

Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/399/walking-up-down-a-level-road-street

Piece of advice: first  absorb this and don't worry about chainging anything. Also, please note the additions of determiners.

You can look up, look up.

You can't change from up to at or along without changing the meaning.
The basic difference is the direction being referred to. To look at the road suggests that your line of sight is at right angles to the road. For example, I might stand in my kitchen and look out of the window at the road, seeing the children riding their bikes and the cars going by.
On the other hand, to look up the road means to look along the road, to see the whole road as far as it goes. For example, I might walk down my driveway to the footpath and turn to look up the road to work out how busy the traffic is today.
In your second example, both up the path and along the path describe a viewpoint of looking parallel to the path. In some cases they could mean the same thing. But there may be an implied difference of elevation. If you want to describe walking on a path to the top of a hill, then up the path is better. If you want to emphasise that the walk is on a flat surface ("They walked along the beach path"), then along is the right choice.

For examples 1 and 2, look up the street, the preposition up means a higher position; ahead; Jennie is sitting at the window and looks TOWARDS (up) the street in a wishful manner, while the second person is both walking and looking in all directions–left, right, and straight ahead. Switching up with look at would not work .
As for no. 3, make his way up […] garden path, “along” could also work here, but I believe "make his way up" suggests there is effort involved; Harry was dragging his cousin's weight and taking him up to his parents' home.
